# Calling the overridden function in abstract class

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class

So i have the `abstract class Worker`, which has the abstract function `computePay`.

The two children classes of this class are `HourlyWorker` and `FixedWorker`,
now i have provided the implementation of `computePay` in both these classes.Now my code says

```
Worker[] w=new worker[2];
w[0]=new HourlyWorker;
w[1]=new FixedWorker;
```

now when i say `w[0].computePay` how am i sure that which computePay is called, 
i know the one from the child class will be called, but which one?

i.e.
If my both the child classes have different implementation of the `computePay` function,
will the following code give me the desired result?

```
w[0].computePay //Prints the pay as per the implementation in HourlyWorker;
w[1].computePay //Prints the pay as per the implementation in FixedWorker;
```

Also i heard about the `instance of` operator/keyword, but i dont know will it be of any use here?

Comment: It's common practice to use `println` statements for debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Java will make sure that the "correct" method gets called.

No need for manual dispatch using instanceof.

> i know the one from the child class will be called, but which one?

A [basic concept of OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is that you don't need to know. You are programming to the interface defined in your abstract class, and don't need to know about which implementation is being used here (or what it does).

Comment: thanks.. will accept the answer as soon as the stackoverflow allows me to.

Comment: @thilo +1 for the link @ karan i guess all answer says the same thing I hope you are more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

> I know the one from the child class will be called, but which one?

The one of the *actual* type of your object. So if your object *is* a `HourlyWorker` (initialized with `new HourlyWorker()`) you will call the `computePay` method of this type.

The `instance of` keyword is used to test if an object is of a specified type. It should not be used in good designs (except when overriding `equals`). It is of no use here. On the contrary, you should rely on the polymorphism as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The methods in java are by default virtual(like in CPP you have to use virtual keyword), so java will make sure the methods are called in respect of object rather than the reference. Abstract method are pure virtual function of C++

Also note that instanceof wont be useful here, so avoid it.